# I am not getting value textfields and dropdowns of reactform in my console

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks, axios, material-ui

```
const handleSubmit= (event)=>{
  debugger;
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  console.log('heelo')

  const body = {
    firstName: formData.get('firstName'),
    lastName: formData.get('lastName'),
    fatherName: formData.get('fatherName'),
    age: formData.get('age'),
    email: formData.get('email'),
    password: formData.get('password'),
    address: formData.get('address'),
    phone: formData.get('phone'),
    campus: campus,
    grade: grade,
    gender: gender
  };
  console.log('Form data:', body);
  console.log('Form data:', formData);

  
}

  
return (
  <>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 

..... //my code//
```

}

export default SignupPage

I am not getting value from textfields in my console in MaterialUi reactjs... I have print the object in console then further work with axios for api call

```
I am not getting value textfields and dropdowns of reactform in my console. I am trying to get object in console of reactform and further will work with axios
```